# Proper pronunciation of ordinal numbers?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

Ok, so these few are easy:

> 1st (first)
>       2nd (second)
>       3rd (third)
>       4th (fourth)
>       ......

And all other ordinal numbers ending in 1, 2 or 3 have their respective values, except for *11th, 12th* and *13th,* as far as I'm concerned.

But when you reach numbers like ***601st***, what is the correct way to pronounce it?

These were options I was going over:

> six hundred and first
>       six hundred first
>       six hundred and oneth (final thought)

So, which one is it? None of them sound 100% right. Have I missed the correct one out completely? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pronunciation appears to differ by dialect.

In British English, it's definitely ***six hundred and first***.

American English appears to drop the *and* in such numbers where BrE includes it, and is presumably ***six hundred first***.

Either audience would understand the other.

It is definitely not **oneth*, just as 1st is itself not *oneth.

Comment: I think it's the same in AmE.

Comment: @Noah I'm sure I've heard "six hundred first", but I may have been mistaken. The US will wake up in a couple of hours' time...

Comment: Back in the early seventies, my grade school teacher drilled into us that, "there is only 1 *and* and it goes at the decimal point as in *six hundred one and 5 tenths*", thus 601 would be six hundred one.  *HOWEVER* I still say six hundred and one as does most everyone I know. So six hundred and first here is common in AmE too.

Comment: In AmE, we consider the *"and"* as optional.

Answer (score 1):

It's *six hundred and first*. For 602nd, you should say *six hundred and second* and so on and on.