# How to pronounce long numbers?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

2,060,700 in words.

Which is correct.

(A). Two million sixty thousand and seven hundred dollars

```
                                OR
```

(B). Two million sixty thousand seven hundred dollars

```
                                OR
```

(C).  Two million and sixty thousand seven hundred dollsrs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper pronunciation of ordinal numbers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81468/proper-pronunciation-of-ordinal-numbers)

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

None of those are wrong. You can use any one of them.

Preference may differ based on location. Just like Americans say and write the date as Month, Day, Year and Europeans (and probably most of the world) use the format of Day, Month, Year. Both are correct.

I am Australian and I would say:
2 million, sixty thousand and seven hundred.

Answer (score 0):

In speech, one would hear any of these.

Caveat: for the purpose of writing amounts in formal documents (including a bank check/cheque), do *not* use "and", except to separate the dollars amount from the cents amount, e.g.

```
 Five dollars and 11 cents
 Five and 11/100 dollars
```

I've actually known a bank refuse a check with "One hundred and fifty dollars".

Answer (score -3):

the second one is correct, actually the way I konw is that one, as far as I know